# How did Jackson get the exact solution to potential in polar coordinates

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

On page 45 of Jackson's Classical Electrodynamics (3ed), He solved a polar potential problem with known source distribution.
$$
\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{\partial}{\partial \rho}\left( \rho\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial \rho} \right)=-g(\rho)\\
\psi(\rho)\bigg|_{\rho=1}=0\\
$$
with the given source
$$
g(\rho)=-5(1-\rho)+10^4\rho^5(1-\rho)^5
$$
To me, this second order Sturm-Liouville ODE can only be solved if we have two boundary conditions, but in this case, we don't know the other BC.

Comment: I thought you needed two boundary conditions as well, you sure you're not missing an implicitly assumed boundary condition? Potential problems often have implicitly assumed boundary conditions...like $\psi(0) = 0$ or something like that.

Comment: Note that there is no point charge at the origin (by which I mean a delta function in $g(\rho)$), so the potential must be regular there (just apply Gauss's law to an infinitesimal ball centred on the origin). So the other boundary condition has to be $\psi'(\rho)|_{\rho=0}=0$.

Comment: Alternately you could just integrate up from $\rho=1$ and figure out what the integration constants need to be for the solution to be finite at the origin.